# Counting columns that have data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query running to fetch month on month data from SQL Server. I need to add an additional column "Count" which captures the count of all the columns that has a value greater than '0'

| Jan | Feb | Mar | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 0 | 25 | 2 |
| 11 | 10 | 4 | 3 |
| 0 | 0 | 7 | 1 |

Here's the SQL query I tried, however soon realized this case expression may not be the optimal way to capture all possible combination.

Can someone suggest a better solution?

```
SELECT 
, P.January as 'Jan'
, P.February as 'Feb'
, P.March as 'Mar',
CASE 
  WHEN P.January > 0 AND P.February > 0 AND P.March > 0 THEN '3'
  WHEN P.January < 0 AND P.February > 0 AND P.March > 0 THEN '2'
  ....
ELSE ''
END as 'Count'
```

Comment: Use a case expression for each column, either 1 or 0, and add them together.

Comment: sign(Jan)+sign(Feb)+sign(Mar)    If negative values you can wrap each column in abs()

Comment: SELECT COUNT(Col1), COUNT(Col2), COUNT(Col3) etcc ...

Comment: FROM whichtable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @JohnCappelletti said in the comments you can use beautiful `Sign` function like this (assuming the values are >=0):

```sql
SELECT 
, P.January as 'Jan'
, P.February as 'Feb'
, P.March as 'Mar'
, Sign(P.January) + Sign(P.February) + Sign(P.March) /*other months*/ as Count
FROM P
```

Answer (score 1):

If no negative values, we can take advantage of the fact that `CONVERT(bit, 13)` yields `1`, and take `SUM` from a `CROSS APPLY`:

```
SELECT s.Jan, s.Feb, s.Mar, 
  [Count] = SUM(CONVERT(int, CONVERT(bit, x.v)))
FROM dbo.YourTableName AS s
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(s.Jan),(s.Feb),(s.Mar)) AS x(v)
GROUP BY s.Jan, s.Feb, s.Mar;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Q8vcJAyH)

If you have negative values that should not count, you can just add `col + ABS(col)` to change negative values to 0, double positive values, and leave 0 untouched.

```
SELECT s.Jan, s.Feb, s.Mar, 
  [Count] = SUM(CONVERT(int, CONVERT(bit, x.v + ABS(x.v))))
  -------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^
FROM dbo.YourTableName AS s
CROSS APPLY (VALUES(s.Jan),(s.Feb),(s.Mar)) AS x(v)
GROUP BY s.Jan, s.Feb, s.Mar;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a flexible solution that is working regardless of the number of columns.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (Jan int, Feb int, Mar INT, Apr INT, May INT);
INSERT @tbl (Jan,Feb,Mar, Apr, May) VALUES
(13, 0,  25, 0, 2),
(11, 10, 4,  1, 18),
(0,  0,  7,  0, 7);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

SELECT t.*
   , [Count] = x.value('count(/root/*[not(text()="0")]/text())', 'INT')
FROM @tbl AS t
CROSS APPLY (SELECT t.* FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE, ROOT('root')) AS t1(x);
```

**Output**

| Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 13 | 0 | 25 | 0 | 2 | 3 |
| 11 | 10 | 4 | 1 | 18 | 5 |
| 0 | 0 | 7 | 0 | 7 | 2 |

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good use case for `IIF`, see the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-iif-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

The query will be this one:

```
SELECT 
Jan, Feb, Mar,
IIF(Jan > 0, 1, 0) + IIF(Feb > 0, 1, 0) + IIF(Mar > 0, 1, 0) AS [Count]
FROM p;
```